# Do I need visa in India

Tags: visas, transit, india, filipino-citizens

Hi i am a Filipino citizen travelling from Dubai to Kochi via Air India (AI934) and then Kochi to Kuala Lumpur via Air Asia (AK38). My booking is a **self transfer** with a 4 hour and 40 mins layover only.

Do I need visa in Kochi, India on the way to Kuala Lumpur?

Answer (score 2):

According to Timatic, yes, you need a visa. https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Transit without a visa is possible for Filipino passengers transiting through:

- Bangalore (BLR), Chennai (MAA), Delhi (DEL), Kolkata (CCU) or Mumbai (BOM) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
- Hyderabad (HYD), with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination. Airlines must obtain the approval from the Immigration before departure.